# What's wrong with \W on non UTF-8 encodings using Scala?

Tags: regex, scala, utf-8

So, I'm looking at the Typesafe Activator tutorial, and [it says](https://github.com/deanwampler/spark-workshop/blob/master/src/main/scala/sparkworkshop/WordCount2.scala)
the regex used;
the similar, non-alphanumeric alternative `\W+`, does not work well
with non-UTF8 character sets!

That seemed like a curious thing to say.

Original comment in full:

```
// Split on non-alphabetic sequences of characters. Note the regex used;
// the similar, non-alphanumeric alternative """\W+""", does not work well
// with non-UTF8 character sets!
```

and the code that follows:

```
val wc = input
    .flatMap(line => line.split("""[^\p{IsAlphabetic}]+"""))
    .map(word => (word, 1))
    .reduceByKey((count1, count2) => count1 + count2)
```

What's the matter with `\W` and non-UTF8 character sets?

Answer (score 1):

The comment doesn't make sense to me.

However, it's true that `\w` by default only recognizes word characters in ASCII range `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, which means that the complement character set `\W` consider the rest of the Unicode (which includes letters from all sorts of languages) as *non-word*s.

`\p{IsAlphabetic}` is a better approximation of word characters, since it includes characters in **Letter** (`Lu`, `Ll`, `Lt`, `Lm`, `Lo`) and **Number, letter** (`Nl`) [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category), plus some more other alpahebetic characters. However, digits (`Nd` category) and combining marks (`Mc` category) are completely missing.

A better solution is to use [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) or the equivalent inline flag `(?U)`, available from Java 7, to make `\w`, `\s` and `\d` (and other predefined character classes) Unicode-aware.

So the snippet of code should be changed into

```
    .flatMap(line => line.split("""(?U)\W+"""))
```

If `(?U)` flag is not available in the particular implementation of Java, it's possible to emulate `\w` with the following character class (just negate it for `\W`):

```
[\p{IsAlphabetic}\p{M}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\u200c\u200d]
```

<sup>**Caveat:** Do note that Unicode character classes like `\p{IsAlphabetic}`, `\p{M}` or `\W` (with `(?U)` flag) may exhibit slightly different behavior for characters added in later versions of Unicode, or characters whose category is changed between versions of Unicode. It is by nature highly dependent on the Unicode repertoire on the system the code is run on.</sup>

Comment: So... [`\W` is equivalent to `[^\p{AlNum}]`, according to Oracle's API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Is the complaint that it's not `[^\p{IsAlphabetic}]`? So, the problem is not using `\W` with non-UTF8, but with Unicode characters generally.

Comment: @IonFreeman: There is no concept of "non-UTF-8" when you hold a String in Java or Scala. String object in Java/Scala is always an array of UTF-16 code units, and data read from file (as bytes) will be decoded and then encoded into UTF-16 as String object. As for `\p{Alnum}`, it's not equivalent to `\w`, since `\w` includes `_`, but those POSIX character class by default only recognizes ASCII character. `\p{IsAlphabetic}` on the other hand, checks for Unicode property "Alphabetic" as defined in Unicode standard.